# Responding to several commenters

Tags: support

On occasions when there are several commentators on a question or answer it can be useful to give a particular response to more than one of these, but SE only allows a response to be directed to a single person. I don't see why can't a message be shouldn't directed to multiple recipients. I think that this might involve a minor change to SE but save the users much time and effort.

Comment: This is a site wide function that will not change. There's a main meta question on it, but no official response: [Why only one @user per comment?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/164681).

Comment: The formal description of the functionality is described here:  [How do comment @replies work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019). Ironically I couldn't put both links in the same comment since there were two `@` signs.

Comment: I find this also very annoying. I cannot say something like "@ABC, I agree with @DEF that this is nice." Sometimes it would really help if one could do such things.

Comment: In addition I would love to see a feature that allows the one that get addressed in the comment to "check" the comment, such that I one can remove it. So if one writes "@xyz, I have edited my question." It would be great if @xyz (and only @xyz) could just "check" the comment. Standard practices are either to upvote the comment if one has read it, but this is not the purpose of the upvote button (and also can be done by different user, i.e. not @xyz), or to write another comment, which may lead to a comment orgy.